# Bayesian classifier and linear regression on dummy variables

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, linear-regression

EDIT: I am finally not so sure about one thing: they say **regression** but not **linear regression**. I may have misunderstood the whole paragraph.

In the book [*Elements of Statistical Learning*, (Hastie-Tibshirani-Friedman)](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf), on page 22, just before paragraph 2.5, they say that for the task of classification, the so-called method Bayes classifier and the classification by largest fitted value of linear regression on dummy variables give the same result.
**Can you tell me what is the precise statement and where to find a proof?**

Let me give you a few details on the context, in order to make the question almost self-contained and to make sure I'm understanding the text correctly.

Let $p$ be an integer, $\mathcal{G}$ be a finite set, and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^p \times \mathcal{G}$ that, for simplicity, we assume to be finitely-supported. Let $A$ be the image of the support of $\mu$ by the first coordinate map.

The Bayes classifier method is a map $\hat{G} : \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ such that for all $x \in A$, $\hat{G}(x) \in argmax (g \mapsto \mu(\{x,g\}))$.

A classification by largest fitted value of the linear regression on dummy variables is defined in a slightly more difficult way: we consider a linear map $\hat{\beta} : \mathbb{R}^{p+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{G}}$ which is a minimizer of the functional $\beta \mapsto EPE(\beta) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^p \times \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{G}}} \sum_{g' \in \mathcal{G}}\left(\textbf{1}_{g' = g} - \beta(x,1)(g)\right)^2 d\mu(x,g)$ and we consider a map $\hat{G}$ such that for all $x \in A$, $\hat{G}(x) \in argmax (g \mapsto \hat{\beta}(x,1)(g))$.

Is it true that (apart from possible non-uniqueness of the two $argmax$ and of the $argmin$ of $EPE$) that the two $\hat{G}$ are equal? Is it true that for all $g \in \mathcal{G}$, and all $x \in A$, $\mu(\{x,g\}) = \hat{\beta}(x,1)(g)$?